# UI Lag/Hiccup in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a viewcontroller which displays all the information in regards to the post. It is doing the job I want it to however there is one problem. I have an imageview that is pulling an image from some firebase storage. They are definetly loading correctly. But my problem is that there are times where I notice the picture changing. There are also times where I notice the background image in the cell which is a blurred image of the image is either not there at all or it is wrong. Is there anything I can do to fix this UI Lag. In the controller that presents this controller I store one instance of this VC and just reuse that same instance as to not create a memory leak. I am not sure if that is wrong implementation or what but it seems as though it may be causing some error.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class EventDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentEvent : Event?{
        didSet{
              let imageURL = URL(string: (currentEvent?.currentEventImage)!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.currentEventImage.af_setImage(withURL: imageURL!)
                self.blurryBackGround.image = self.currentEventImage.image
            }
            currentEventTime.text = currentEvent?.currentEventTime
            currentEventDate.text = currentEvent?.currentEventDate
            eventNameLabel.text = currentEvent?.currentEventName.uppercased()
            guard let currentZip = currentEvent?.currentEventZip else{
                return
            }
            let firstPartOfAddress = (currentEvent?.currentEventStreetAddress)!  + "\n" + (currentEvent?.currentEventCity)! + ", " + (currentEvent?.currentEventState)!
            let secondPartOfAddress = firstPartOfAddress + " " + String(describing: currentZip)
            addressLabel.text = secondPartOfAddress
            descriptionLabel.text = currentEvent?.currentEventDescription
            descriptionLabel.font = UIFont(name: (descriptionLabel.font?.fontName)!, size: 14)
            updateWithSpacing(lineSpacing: 7.0)
            navigationItem.title = currentEvent?.currentEventName.capitalized
            setupAttendInteraction()
        }
    }
```

Upon checking the currentEventImage.image it seems to be nil upon entering screen

Comment: wait why did I get a downvote

Comment: nvm i fixed it myself

Answer (score 0):

Change/changed

```
self.blurryBackGround.image = self.currentEventImage.image
```

to

```
self.blurryBackGround.af_setImage(withURL: imageURL!)
```